# orientation change VS jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The website: http://negativgraffiti.hu/uj/

If you jumps from one page to another, every page has a different height, but they are all in one div, just they are not visible all the time.

I'm resizing the parent div everytime to the current page's height (not the full code, just a sample):

```
var magassag = jQuery("#post-5");    
var egymagas = jQuery(".elsofo").height();
if (i == 1) {
    magassag.animate({
        height: egymagas
    }, 100 );
}
```

it's working fine, but when i test it on tablet/mobile the height is ruins when i change the orientation, and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).on('resize', fn)` to detect window resizing.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    // re-animate the height for the current page
});
```

Although this works fine for tablet resizing, it will be very inefficient for desktop users who are resizing the window with their mouse. It is good to `throttle` the resize callback for that reason.

```
// Use `throttle` from any of the various throttle libraries available.

$(window).on('resize', throttle(function() {
    // re-animate the height for the current page
}));
```